# Can I plug my Xbox into my laptop?

Tags: xbox-360, pc

I currently have a HDMI cable hookup on my computer, I was wondering if I could play my Xbox on my computer via HDMI cable?

Is this just a terrible idea? Any help will be appreciated.

My laptop information can be found [here](http://ps3-www1.us.dell.com/us/en/gen/notebooks/inspiron-14r-n4110/pd.aspx?refid=inspiron-14r-n4110&s=gen)

Comment: is it an input or an output?

Comment: @ratchetfreak I am using http://ps3-www1.us.dell.com/us/en/gen/notebooks/inspiron-14r-n4110/pd.aspx?refid=inspiron-14r-n4110&s=gen and it hasn't given a straight answer :/

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would bet that this is impossible. Connecting an HDMI output (on the Xbox) to another HDMI output (on the computer) is unlikely to do anything useful. Plus, that would be a completely separate problem to connect to Live.

Comment: If its a laptop - I don't know any which has hdmi *input*, so I'd say you can't (unless there is something special with that model, not very likely). For a desktop, you'd just connect to the monitor (bypassing the 'computer' part)

Comment: Also, you should put the laptop info in description; and maybe specify playing Xbox using that screen (remove the Live part) since that seems to be the real question

Comment: @kotekzot Yes, but use my computer as a TV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot, unless your computer has a video input, which most do not. If your monitor is separate from the computer you can plug your Xbox into it instead. There are [internal](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20capture%20card&tbm=shop&oq=usb%20capture%20card&gs_l=products-cc.12...0.0.0.55414.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&tbm=shop&q=pci%20capture%20card&oq=pci%20capture%20card&gs_l=serp.3..0.204822.205642.0.205844.6.6.0.0.0.2.380.993.3j1j0j2.6.0...0.0.AhoLEsUbZzA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=b037ca43b881b3eb&biw=1647&bih=926) and [external capture cards](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20capture%20card&tbm=shop&oq=usb%20capture%20card&gs_l=products-cc.12...0.0.0.55414.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.) available that could allow you to input the video and audio your Xbox produces.

Here's a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peLdwr1ACr0&feature=related) that explains how to use an external capture card.

Answer (score 4):

I use my laptop as a TV all the time, well at work. I pack my laptop and XBOX, and play at work. It is possible, it's a portable TV for me.
I just plug in the HDMI from the XBOX to my laptop.

Comment: How does this work, does your laptop have an HDMI input port? or are you using software or driver to do this?

Comment: Could you provide your laptop model? I doubt many laptop models have a HDMI input

Answer (score 1):

The HDMI port on the laptop is only a output port for plugging in a external screen.
If you want to use the laptop as the screen and play the xbox on the laptop you need a capture card.

One of my favorit youtubers posted a video with a promotion for some sort of discount on a capture card in collaboration with Machinima.

[ZackScott video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKbuR-yqpt8&feature=plcp) [Roxio capture card.](http://www.roxio.com/enu/promotions/landing/machinima/game-capture/console/overview.html?source=mac_0312_dir8)

Also it is clearly a payed advertisement from ZackScott if it changes anything.

Answer (score -2):

You need a HDMI input to do so. It's the only way i know. Or you can spend a couple hundred bucks on an HD PVR.